# Why won't item utilize texture I made?

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling, minecraft-forge

(Using IntelliJ to code everything)
I'm making a Minecraft Mod and when I go to test my custom item out the name works perfectly with spaces and all, but for some odd reason it won't use the texture, instead when loading the texture it gives the error:

> "Unable to load model: 'bullets:really_long_item_name_here#inventory' referenced from: bullets:really_long_item_name_here#inventory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: bullets:models/item/really_long_item_name_here.json"

The image for the texture is a .png file and has the correct name.

Heres the code within the models/item directory

```
{
  "parent": "item/generated",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "bullets:items/really_long_item_name_here"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### For IntelliJ users

In the project tree IntelliJ shows subfolder as `folderA.folderB` instead of `folderA/folderB`.

It took me half an hour to realize that I created a folder called `assets.examplemodid` instead of  folder `examplemodid` inside `assets`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you put this json in a wrong location. As your stacktrace says: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: bullets:models/item/really_long_item_name_here.json` means it can't find your model, which **have to** be in `resources/assets/<modid>/models/item`. Then, if your texture has a proper location (`resources/assets/<modid>/textures/items/really_long_item_name_here.png`) it should work.

Comment: I just now realized that the .json file inside (resources/assets/<modid>/models/item) was named incorrectly.
Thank you for your effort though!